# Does regenerating a wildcard SSL with CA invalidate it across previous properties/sites?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain

I'm migrating my company's primary website to a new production environment. I'm going to rekey and regenerate the SSL against the new production environment. The SSL cert we have is a wildcard cert that covers several properties and sub-domains.

**Does regenerating a wildcard SSL with the CA invalidate it across previous properties/sub-domains?** I'm assuming that if I regenerate the SSL, I'll need to install the respective certs to all environments I wish to cover with SSL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: All the SSL vendors I've worked with have a separate process for revocation of the old cert that you have to trigger. Best to ask your vendor, though, to be certain of that.

Comment: My experience with CAs is that they dislike having two certs with the same contents valid at the same time, so  they will likely revoke the old cert after the new one is issued.  That is CA dependent though.

Comment: @JasonMartin That was not my experience with Comodo, Geotrust, Amazon ECM, or Let's Encrypt. I can't speak for other vendors.